# Multilanguage support for images in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a desktop app build using .net. I want it to support multilanguages. I am able to do that using resources. Issue is what should I do for images which have text? Should I include all images for separate languages? If so then this will make it difficult and also will increase its size.

I just read that in Android there is "9 patch image", isn't there something similar?

I wish to add background image, and write text on top of that. This background image should resize without change in quality of the image automatically to the size of text in that language.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Yeah. quite of obvious taht you either include images with text i every langauge or generate them - which has other issues and is often not feasible. No real question here. And syntacticall you totally do not ASK ANYTHING.

Comment: Hi,
1) I just don't know if there is any utility to do that, that is generate image at runtime depending upon text size. 
2) How are multilanguage support done for images (text image)? 
3) Or do I have to include images for all the languages I support?
4)Suppose I have a image on which a text is written SAVE. Now if I have to support five more languages, do I have to include FIVE images with corresponding TEXT. Its cumbersome .

Thanks.
Sujit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of any way to avoid separate images with WinForms.  WPF, no problem.  Web app, no problem.  I played around with both text and image on a Button control, but that does not scale fully.  I tried using a label over a PIctureBox, but it is impossible to achieve transparency with a Label control.  I also tried this using a WebBrowser control--such a thing could possibly work, but would take some further research and would probably change your deployment dramatically (since you would need to make the localization available from some http server).

So I think there is no easy way to do this--I could find nothing easier than maintaining the images separately.

Comment: Thanks Onemancat. Looks like I have to maintain separate images.

Comment: Do you mean WinForms when you typed "WebForms"?

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, i had text displayed on top of images. Since the site was multilingual, so no text was part of the images. Instead text was displayed on top of the images, using css properties for absolute position. This had to be tested in all browsers, with multiple languages, as the text size varies in each language, this might break the UI. so enough space has to be provided for text considering all supported languages

Comment: Your solution was for web programming.  OP is about Windows programming.  In a browser, it is quite easy to layer text on top of an image.